# Android Gradle library dependency

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle

Hi I have following android project:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add another dependency: https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview.
I tried adding

```
    compile 'com.mobeta.android.dslv:drag-sort-listview:0.6.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

but it doesn't work. How can I add this project as a Gradle dependency?
I saw that there is an option to copy this library as a subdirectory in my project dir. How should I include such a project?

Comment: you can download that github project and make it into a jar and then use compile files to use it if the current method isnt working for you

Answer (score 5):

The author of the library has to upload @aar bundle to maven central repository to make it work. As you can see drag sort listview is no longer mainted by author. You can use repo from the community as temporal solution.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mobeta.android.dslv:drag-sort-listview:0.6.1'
}
```

In general case you have to download sources and add them as library to your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately adding this repository doesn't help :( I tried adding drag-sort-listview library in my projects root directory and gradle dependency: compile project(":drag-sort-listview") but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you press `Sync project with gradle files`? Is there any error while runnin `assembleDebug`?

Comment: I did not press it. I build an jar archive and copied it into libs folder as  Android2390 said and I think it is working now. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I like to recommend you to use this library instead.

I thinks https://github.com/ened is thanksfully made the library for gradle and maintained it for a while.

```
compile 'asia.ivity.android:drag-sort-listview:1.0'
<dependency>
    <groupId>asia.ivity.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>drag-sort-listview</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asia.ivity.android/drag-sort-listview/1.0

https://github.com/ened/drag-sort-listview